# JavaScript Variable inside a String

Tags: javascript, syntax

i've just started learning JavaScript and came across a little problem.

```
var id;
function replay(id){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='<form action="./replay.php?uid= method="get"><hr><input type="submit" name="qpost" class="replay_key" value="Post" style="background-color: #a9d22c;"></form>';  
}
```

i'm trying to add the variable "id" after but can't figure out the syntax

```
<form action="./replay.php?uid=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='<form action="./replay.php?uid=' + id + '" method="get"><hr><input type="submit" name="qpost" class="replay_key" value="Post" style="background-color: #a9d22c;"></form>';
```

Essentially you want:

```
something = 'string literal' + variableName + 'another string literal';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//var id;
// using id for example 12
var id = 12;
function replay(id){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='<form action="./replay.php?uid=' + id + ' method="get"><hr><input type="submit" name="qpost" class="replay_key" value="Post" style="background-color: #a9d22c;"></form>';  
}
```

Comment: Won't that give `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`? Or an error about the missing closing `)`?

Comment: In other words, "Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
replay(id);
}
is just for fireing the function in Jquery
Forgot Javascript was asked and not Jquery 
just delete the last 3 lines

Answer (score 0):

A string is a sequence of characters basically. One very useful thing you can do with strings is concatenate (join) them using the `+` operator:

```
var longString = 'This is ' + 'a long' + ' string'; // "This is a long string"
```

The easiest way to insert something in the middle of a string is to concatenate the begining of the string, your something and the end of the string:

```
var mySomething = 'a long';

var longString = 'This is ' + mySomething + ' string'; // "This is a long string"
```

You can do the same for your id:

```
var id;
function replay(id){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='<form action="./replay.php?uid=' + id + '" method="get"><hr><input type="submit" name="qpost" class="replay_key" value="Post" style="background-color: #a9d22c;"></form>';  
}
```

Resulting HTML prettyfied(for id = 123):

```
<form action="./replay.php?uid=123" method="get">
  <hr>
  <input type="submit" name="qpost" class="replay_key" value="Post" style="background-color: #a9d22c;">
</form>
```

Notice how i also added the closing quotes after the id!